# multer.diskStorage not working properly in post request

Tags: node.js, express, multer

i an trying to save video in my filesystem using post request and multer is throwning me error

```
var storage = multer.diskStorage({   
destination: function(req, file, cb) { 
 cb(null, './uploads');    
}, 
 filename: function (req, file, cb) { 
 cb(null , file.originalname);   
 }
 });
 var upload = multer({ storage: storage })

 app.post('/init-video', upload.single('file'), function (req, res) {
   res.send("bruh")
 )}
```

Comment: Please take a moment and complete the tour: https://stackoverflow.com/tour, read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Explain your expected behavor and what error occours.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.